# Проблема с аутентификацией через OmniAuth Вконтакте

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vkontakte-api, heroku

использую Ruby on Rails, gem omniauth-vkontakte. при попытке аутентификации ВК выдает `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"client_id is incorrect"}`, в логах **heroku**: 
`NoMethodError (undefined method  'provider' for nil:NilClass):
app/models/user.rb:5:in 'from_omniauth'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:3:in 'create'`

app_id и app_secret верны, несколько раз проверял :(

**`config/initializers/omniauth.rb`** :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Omniauth::Builder do
    provider :vkontakte, ENV['app_id'], ENV['app_secret'],
    scope: 'public_profile', display: 'page', image-size: 'square'
end
```

**`models/user.rb`**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages, dependent: :delete_all
    class << self
        def from_omniauth(auth)
            provider = auth.provider
            uid = auth.uid
            info = auth.info.symbolize.keys!
            user = User.find_or_initialize_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)
            user.name = info.name
            user.avatar_url = info.image
            user.profile_url = info.urls.send(provider.capitalize.to_sym)
            user.save!
            user
        end
    end
end
```

**`controllers/sessions_controller.rb`**:

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth_auth'])
    cookies[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Грохнулась пятая строчка `user.rb`, якобы вызов метода `#provider` у `nil`.
- Видимо, `auth` имеет значение `nil`. Как так вышло?
- В первой строчке `SessionsController#create` на месте `auth` `request.env['omniauth_auth']`

...

Ну да, там `nil`, такого ключа в `env` (среде) запроса не существует. Ключ **не тот**.

Вместо `omniauth_auth` нужен `omniauth.auth`.

— [`intridea/OmniAuth/README.md`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-application)

```
def auth_hash
  request.env['omniauth.auth']
end
```

Comment: спасибо! проглядел эту ошибку, исправил, теперь по логам она не возникает, но сам ВК все так же передает `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"client_id is incorrect"}`. несколько раз перепроверил выданный мне app_id и app_secret, все верно

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 это уже другой вопрос, для ответа на который информации у меня нет. Волшебства не бывает, видимо, вы где-то всё же ошиблись. Проследите, какие запросы делает браузер клиента, проблема, видимо, будет заметна даже там.

Comment: основной запрос идет на `method=GET path="/auth/vkontakte"`

Comment: исправлено, просто redirect URI не тот указал в настройках приложения, удалил его - и заработало :)